# Generate all possible test papers from txt files

Tags: java, arrays, random, combinations

I would like to build a simple program in Java. But I don't know where to begin.
What should I think of when developing a flow or pseudocode before programming the solution.

I have two txt files, containing questions. One file has 60 questions and the other 432 questions.
I would like to generate a test paper and export it to an txt file, for example I want to create a test paper containing first part 10 questions out of 60
and second part 12 questions out of 432

However, I would like to calculate how many variations are possible? And subsequently I would like to generate them.

Could you guide me in thinking, and how to devise something,

I don't want a complete solution, because I would like to challenge myself to develop/program it. But a start would be helpful.

Comment: Start simple.  How many ways are there to pick 10 questions from your first question bank of 60 questions?  Presumably do not want to have the same question appear twice, so allow for that in your calculation.  For the moment you don't need to think about how to program it, just think about how to work out the number of combinations.  Then answer the same question for 12 out of 432.

Comment: I think one can shuffle those question (randomize) and select a fixed amount of questions.

Comment: Yes you can.  Now think of a way to shuffle only 10 or 12 questions from a longer list.  Start by looking at the Fisher-Yates shuffle and think of a way to stop it when you have shuffled the list enough so as not to waste time..

Comment: At the rate of 1 billion tests per second, it will take you over 3 quintillion years to generate all possible tests (this is assuming that you don't care about the order of the questions on the test but rather just care about which questions are chosen. If you care about the order it will take you much longer).  Perhaps you want to shoot for something less ambitious.

Comment: By the way `devise` is an authentication gem used with Ruby on Rails and has nothing at all to do with your question. Please make sure that you know the meaning of a tag before using that tag. I removed it.

Comment: sorry, i didn't mean the word devise of an programming language, merely the english word devise (in sense devise a flow / structure to tackle the problem).

Answer (score 0):

Start by finding the objects you see in your problem: `Question`, `Test`, `QuestionRepository`. Then think of how you would populate them. For example, `QuestionRepository` should be able to populate itself from a text file. In doing that the method should rely on a `Question` being created from the next chunk of a file stream. A `Test` should specify the number of questions and the `QuestionRepository` it is intended to pick questions from. Etc. Pay attention not to mix contingent information with your conceptual model of objects. In your case, do not tie the behavior or your objects to the fact that your data come from text files. Instead, separate those elements in instance creation methods that incapsulate these details.